# convert "a week ago" into an actual date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets document where a scraper gets reviews from google maps, I want to sort them by date but the only date the reviews contain are the human readable "XX days/weeks/months/years ago" so just sorting that column doesn't work.

the actual values I get:

- a day ago
- 2 days ago
- 3 days ago
- 4 days ago
- 5 days ago
- 6 days ago
- a week ago
- 2 weeks ago
- 3 weeks ago
- a month ago
- 2 months ago
- ...
- 11 months ago
- a year ago
- 2 years ago

Obviously I won't be able to get the actual date for reviews made more than 1 week ago, but an estimate would be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
=index(if(A1:A<>"",today()-(switch(iferror(regexextract(A1:A,"(day|week|month|year)"),),"day",1,"week",7,"month",365.25/12,"year",365.25,)*iferror(substitute(regexextract(A1:A,"([\da]+)\ "),"a",1),)),))
```

Replace `today()` with the scraped date, which in the example, could be `datevalue("2021-10-06")`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### You can also achieve this using Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {
    var obj = {
        'a': 1,
        'two': 2,
        'three': 3,
        'four': 4,
        'five': 5,
        'six': 6,
        'seven': 7,
        'eight': 8,
        'nine': 9,
        'ten': 10,
        'eleven': 11,
        'twelve': 12,
        'thirteen': 13,
        'fourteen': 14,
        'fifteen': 15,
        'sixteen': 16,
        'seventeen': 17,
        'eighteen': 18,
        'nineteen': 19,
        'twenty': 20
    };

    var time = {
        'day': 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        'week': 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        'month': 2.628e+9,
        'year': 3.154e+10
    }

    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let col = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 7, 1).getValues();
    let now = new Date();


    for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        namedDate = col[i][0].toString().split(' ');
        console.log(namedDate[0])
        if (namedDate[2] == "ago") {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(namedDate[0]) && namedDate[1].toString().includes('day')) {
                var newDate = new Date(now.getTime() - obj[namedDate[0]] * time['day'])
                sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(newDate);
            } else if ((obj.hasOwnProperty(namedDate[0]) && namedDate[1].toString().includes('week'))) {
                var newDate = new Date(now.getTime() - obj[namedDate[0]] * time['week'])
                sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(newDate);
            } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(namedDate[0]) && namedDate[1].toString().includes('month')) {
                var newDate = new Date(now.getTime() - obj[namedDate[0]] * time['month'])
                sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(newDate);
            } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(namedDate[0]) && namedDate[1].toString().includes('year')) {
                var newDate = new Date(now.getTime() - obj[namedDate[0]] * time['year'])
                sheet.getRange(i + 1, 2).setValue(newDate);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Explanation

You can see that in the script above there are two objects which represent the words and their corresponding value in numbers. The `obj` object is responsible for translating the number strings into numbers and the `time` object is used for associating the number of milliseconds corresponding to each time frame. Afterwards (assuming that your readable dates are in the `A` column), the values are retrieved and the following methods are being applied to each one of them in order to get the date wanted:

- each human readable date is split in three strings such that each string represents the **amount** (such as `a`, `one` and so on), the **time frame** (`day`, `week` and so on) and **past/future** (`ago`, `upfront`);
- the new date is being built based on these three values and by finding the corresponding values in the `obj` and `time` objects;
- the new date is being pasted in the `B` column.

After the script is executed this is how the sheet will end up looking like:

[image: after the script is being executed]

#### Note

Please bear in mind that in the script above only the case in which you need to find past dates has been handled. If you wish to calculate futures dates as well, you will have to add another condition and add values instead of subtracting them.

Moreover, depending on the maximum `amount` you wish to pass in order to calculate the new date, you might have to modify the script as in its current state it only deals with `amount`s until `20`.

#### Reference

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues());
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setValue(Object));
- [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).